# Why does the match operator's "match-only-once" optimization only apply with the "?" delimiter?

Tags: regex, perl

From the docs (`perldoc -f m`)

> If `?` is the delimiter, then a match-only-once rule applies, described in `m?*PATTERN*?` below.

The "match-only-once rule" doesn't' seem to be defined anywhere, but it seems to be a real optimization,

```
use Benchmark qw(:all) ;
use constant HAYSTACK => "this is a test string";
my $needle = "test";

cmpthese(-1, {
    'questionmark'  => sub { if ( HAYSTACK =~ m?$needle?n ) { 1 } },
    'backslash'     => sub { if ( HAYSTACK =~ m/$needle/n ) { 1 } },
});
```

With the results,

```
                   Rate    backslash questionmark
backslash     9267717/s           --         -57%
questionmark 21588328/s         133%           --
```

This makes me wonder why is the behavior in `m//` in scalar context such that it even needs this behavior? Let's take for example the output

```
perl -E'say "FOOOOOO" =~ m/O/' # returns 1
```

If it's not even counting the `O` what does it do after the first match such that it's twice as slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion here is that "once" in *"match-only-once"* is in reference to the calling context of the `m??` not in reference to matching once the needle inside the haystack, and ignoring subsequent matches of the needle inside the haystack. So if `m??` is called many times without reset, only the first one that matches will return the match.

```
sub foo { return "foo" =~ m?o? };

say foo(); # 1
say foo(); # undef
reset();
say foo(); # 1
```

Answer (score 7):

> The "match-only-once rule" doesn't' seem to be defined anywhere, […]

"A match-only-once rule" is a description of the rule — it's a rule saying that `m?PATTERN?` matches only once — not an official name that you can use to search. The text that you quote is pulled from [the perlop manpage](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html), so when it says "described in `m?*PATTERN*?` below", it's referring to this part of that manpage:

> **`m?PATTERN?msixpodualngc`**
>
> This is just like the `m/PATTERN/` search, except that it matches only once between calls to the `reset()` operator. This is a useful optimization when you want to see only the first occurrence of something in each file of a set of files, for instance. Only `m??` patterns local to the current package are reset.
>
> ```perl
> while (<>) {
>     if (m?^$?) {
>         # blank line between header and body
>      }
> } continue {
>     reset if eof;    # clear m?? status for next file
> }
> ```
>
> Another example switched the first "latin1" encoding it finds to "utf8" in a pod file:
>
> ```perl
> s//utf8/ if m? ^ =encoding \h+ \K latin1 ?x;
> ```

---

> This makes me wonder why is the behavior in `m//` in scalar context such that it even needs this behavior?

Even in scalar context, `m//` or `m??` may be called many times between resets, and if so then the two behave differently. (You can see this in the first snippet above. It's also the reason that your benchmarks give different performance results: the version with `m?$needle?n` only does a regex match the first time the function is called — it just returns 'no match' on all subsequent calls — whereas the version with `m/$needle/n` does a regex match every time.)

Comment: Just to be clear, I was reading `perldoc -f m` which has none of this. But it looks like the short of it is the match-once-rule is referring to the context of the `m??`. Where as I thought it was in reference (after reading `perldoc -f -m`) to the amount of times it would go searching for needle in haystack.

Comment: Re: "Just to be clear, I was reading `perldoc -f m` which has none of this": Oh, right, sorry, you mentioned that in your question. It looks like `perldoc -f m` just gives part of the perlop manpage, not sure how they decided what to include there.

Comment: @Evan Carroll, If you look in perlop, `m//` and `m??` are documented separately. `perldoc -f m` pulls the docs for `m//`

Comment: @Evan Carroll, As for why there's a speed difference, your test are not equivalent. `questionmark` attempts to match once, matches once, never attempts to match after the first attempt, and never matches after the first attempt. `backslash`, on the other hand, attempts to match every time, and matches every time.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: I see that you've un-accepted this answer (and if I'm not mistaken, downvoted it) and posted your own. You don't owe me an explanation, obviously, but if you feel that there's some problem with the answer in its current form, I'm all ears.

Comment: I feel like questions should be answered with an attempt to understand the confusion first. I don't believe that happened here. I believe you dumped docs, and moreover left a vague note which could confuse people into thinking I didn't read the docs fully (I did, just the wrong one). Moreover, I believe you said twice as much text and it's still not as clear what *"match-only-once"* rule actually means. But lastly, I can accept all of these problems above, I just wanted to clarify and you rolled it back. So I used the only tools in my shed to correct that. =) Take care.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: I rolled back because of grammar and clarity issues, and fast-followed with edits that I thought addressed the concerns underlying your edit? Re: "I feel like questions should be answered with an attempt to understand the confusion first": I agree. I thought you had two confusions: how/where to find the doc, and how this feature worked, where the latter was a result of not being able to find the doc. So I thought that linking to and quoting the doc, and then calling out the key issue afterward, was the best way to address both. I'm sorry if that left you feeling unheard.